# Value radio button

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola amigos estoy intentando traer los values de los radio button. Si el value que obtengo es 75%-100% me aparezca seleccionado esa opcion y asi sucesivamente. Los estoy haciendo con un if. Pero siempre me selecciona el primero o el ultimo y a veces obtengo el value 0%-25% y no me lo respeta. Gracias de antemano

Grupo de radio button

```
            <label id="capacidad" class="lbl-texto-reg"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="75%-100%" id="desetentacincocien" class="k-radio">
            <label id="075" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="desetentacincocien"></label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="50%-75%" id="idcincuenta" class="k-radio">
            <label id="50" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idcincuenta"></label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="25%-50%" id="idveinticinco" class="k-radio">
            <label id="60" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idveinticinco"></label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="0%-25%" id="idcero" class="k-radio">
            <label id="70" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idcero"></label>
            <br />



        </div>
```

Archivo javascript

```
var des = $("input:radio[name=setentacien]:checked").val()
                if (des == "75%-100%"); {

                    $('#desetentacincocien').prop('checked', true);
                    $('#idcero').prop('checked', false);

                }

                if (des =="50%-75%"); {

                    $('#idcincuenta').prop('checked', true);

                }

                if (des == "25%-50%"); {

                    $('#idveinticinco').prop('checked', true);

                }

                if (des == "0%-25%"); {

                    $('#idcero').prop('checked', true);

                }
```

Comment: Pero ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer en sí? Los radio con el mismo `name` se seleccionan uno a la vez y si quieres saber cuál fue el seleccionado y su valor puedes usar un *listener*. ¿No será que estás enfocando mal la solución del problema?

Comment: Esos datos que se ven en la imagen ya los traigo desde una tabla sql. Y quiero mostrarlos en una vista. Con los input text no hay problema ya que obtengo los values bien. Pero con los radio button no. Porque en ese ejemplo de la imagen me deberia aparecer seleccionado el value "75%-100%"  que es el correcto correspondiente a ese proveedor, y como ve me selecciona el "0%-25%" . No se si me explico!! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No, no se entiende todavía. Di qué es cada cosa en la pregunta. El código HTML que hay luego de la imagen ¿qué es? Aquí obtendrías el valor del radio que esté chequeado: `var des = $("input:radio[name=setentacien]:checked").val()` pero, ¿qué radio debe venir chequeado y por qué? No sé... pero tengo la impresión de que tu código está mal planteado y das demasiadas vueltas para resolver algo sencillo.

Comment: El dato lo traes de base de datos o estas creando un evento onchange()?

Comment: Para ver si entiendo tu planteamiento. Tú tienes un valor según el cual quieres que se active un radio button u otro? O lo que quieres es que el usuario pulse en un radio button y se actualice un valor? O quieres las dos cosas? Quieres partir de un valor y que se active un radio button pero cuando el usuario pulse otro que se actualice el valor? Creo que especificar esto debería ser el primer paso. A partir de ahí, podemos empezar a resolverlo, pero, como siempre, antes de pensar en la respuesta hay que tener clara la pregunta.

Comment: Asi es tengo un valor y quiero que se acive un radio button u otro de acuerdo al value que traiga de la base de datos.

Comment: @NoéTorres como te trae los valores,en enteros?

Comment: Asi es. En enteros

Comment: No tiene sentido lo que estás haciendo en tu código.Estás chequeando un radio button para volverlo al estado `checked` .¿por qué estás reevaluando los input para volverlos a chequear? debajo te he puesto un ejemplo si recibieses el parámetro y se chequease automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias!! Ya lo resolví!!

Answer (score 0):

si quieres hacer una escucha genérica y si sólo tienes esos radio-button, tendrías que modificar `var des = $("input:radio[name=setentacien]:checked").val()`.Modifico la respuesta,para que sea más específico.Entiendo con el cierre del div,que está dentro de un div.Recogería el valor del input que esta seleccionado y que está dentro de un div específico.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on('click',function(){
 var respuesta = $("#cantidad").val();

 if(respuesta < 25){
  $("#idcero").prop('checked',true);
 }
 if(respuesta <= 50 && respuesta >25){
  $("#idveinticinco").prop('checked',true);
 }
 if(respuesta <= 75 && respuesta > 50){
  $("#idcincuenta").prop('checked',true);
 }
 if(respuesta < 100 && respuesta > 75){
  $("#desetentacincocien").prop('checked',true);
 }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cantidad" type="text"></input>
<div id="caja">
  <label id="capacidad" class="lbl-texto-reg"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="75%-100%" id="desetentacincocien" class="k-radio">
            <label id="075" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="desetentacincocien">75%-100%</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="50%-75%" id="idcincuenta" class="k-radio">
            <label id="50" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idcincuenta">50%-75%</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="25%-50%" id="idveinticinco" class="k-radio">
            <label id="60" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idveinticinco">25%-50%</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="setentacien" value="0%-25%" id="idcero" class="k-radio">
            <label id="70" style="color:#757575;" class="k-radio-label" for="idcero">0%-25%</label>
            <br />
        </div>
<button type="button">pulsa</button>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: 2 sugerencias: La primera añadir el eventto en el `input:radio[name=setentacien]` y la segunda que contra más especifico mejor, tu has puesto `input:radio:checked` para el `val()` pero pienso que sería mejor respetar el name ya que sería más especifico y podría solucionar futuros problemas `input:radio[name=setentacien]:checked` (lo que le faltaba era el `;`)

Comment: @matahombres los names que tiene el,son iguales.Si lo que se quiere es especificar más,recorrería el DOM dentro del div en el que estan metidos para ser mas específicos,pero lo que te digo,si se quiere por nombre,tendrñia que ser un nombre para cada uno.El ejemplo que he hecho es genérico

Comment: No nos ha dicho ningún div por lo que en mi opinión se tendría que especificar lo máximo posible sin hacer un caso tan genérico (ya que puede haber más formularios con radios en la página)

Comment: si te fijas al final de lo que manda,eso está metido en un div